# React-Native: Get X and Y coordinates of draggable Object using panResponder.panHandlers (nativeElement)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app, which provides the design of Different shapes like Square and Circle, I have used the following Library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable

At the time of creating my drawing view its working fine, but at the time of edit that drawing, I want to move Circle and Square from its previous saved position to its new position, but when I am trying to set my previous last position from the DB, I can't get perfect position of X and Y.
[image]

When I debug, **I am getting touch position of the object, not the X and Y position of the object**

this is my code :

1. I used draggable class for creating an object [Draggable](https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable/blob/master/Draggable.js),
2. In my Component :

   ```
                     <Draggable
                          renderSize={68}
                          renderColor='rad'
                          x={80.80097961425781}
                          y={72.79156494140625}
                          renderText='B'
                          pressDrag={()=>alert('touched!!')}
                          pressDragRelease={({ nativeEvent }) => { console.log(nativeEvent);}}
                          reverse={false}
                      />
   ```

Here is my Question: 
 
1. How can I get X and Y from `nativeElement`, 
'nativeElement` property are :    **nativeEvent**

```
ChangedTouches - Array of all touch events that have changed since the last event
identifier - The ID of the touch
locationX - The X position of the touch, relative to the element
locationY - The Y position of the touch, relative to the element
pageX - The X position of the touch, relative to the root element
pageY - The Y position of the touch, relative to the root element
target - The node id of the element receiving the touch event
timestamp - A time identifier for the touch, useful for velocity calculation
touches - Array of all current touches on the screen
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @vignesh nope, I didn't get any solution.

Comment: thanks. Don't go with react-native-draggable. Create your own with pan responder.that's working fine

Answer (score 1):

I used `react-native-draggable` in a project too. `pageX`, `pageY` are the coordinates of your actual touch, while `locationX`, `locationY` are the offset of your touch from the top-left of the object. You didn't specify how you're rendering the shapes, but for instance if you're rendering an image to drag, you can get the exact top-left coordinates by getting (`pageX-locationX`), (`pageY-locationY`).  And you can pull them out of `nativeEvent` like this:

```
<Draggable
  renderSize={68}
  renderColor='rad'
  x={80.80097961425781}
  y={72.79156494140625}
  renderText='B'
  onDragRelease={(e) => {console.log("pageX, pageY = " + e.nativeEvent.pageX + ", " + e.nativeEvent.pageY);
  console.log("locX, locY = " + e.nativeEvent.locationX + ", " + e.nativeEvent.locationY)}}>
  reverse={false}
/>
```

Also, I changed `pressDragRelease` to `onDragRelease`; not sure if you wrapped `onDragRelease` in your own separate function or you have a different version or something, but in mine it's `onDrag` / `onDragRelease`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the bounds of your Draggable in the next arguments of your callback.

```
<Draggable
  ...
  onDragRelease={(e, gestureState, bounds) => { console.log(bounds); }}
/>
```